# Visualize star schema by using an application

Tags: data-warehouse, business-intelligence

If you work with data warehouse and you see couple of fact and dimension table in the SQL server and you want to review everything in a holistic view that would be in the picture below.

Is there any application that can extract tables from the database and display them in a user-friendly approach that would appear in the same picture below?

// Fullmetalboy

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is [many](http://www.databaseanswers.org/modelling_tools.htm) of them, choose a right tool for you.

Comment: Which of these tool do you recommend?

Comment: Embarcadero ER/Studio Data Architect